# Rails 5 , render a form without specific input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form-for

I am trying to render a partial form for editing but i don't want a specific part of that form to show up in the edit action. I am using the normal format render.

```
<%= render 'form', link: @link %>
```

and i don't want to show a specific division

```
<div class="form-group">
<%= f.label :Description %><br>
<%= f.text_area :description, class: "form-control" %>
```

Thank you,

Comment: `link.persisted?` if true, means that you're editing it, if false, is a new link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that by something like: only show this `div` if the object is a new record:

```
<% if f.object.new_record? %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :Description %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Another approach would be to pass an extra argument to the partial:

```
<% if allow_description %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :Description %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And then:

```
# new action
<%= render 'form', link: @link, allow_description: true %>

# edit action
<%= render 'form', link: @link, allow_description: false %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the div with a `if` like this

```
<% if @link.new_record? %>
  <div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :Description %><br>
  <%= f.text_area :description, class: "form-control" %>
<% end %>
```